# Use multiple background colors in labels

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, background, jlabel

I'm building a `JFrame` and I want to have 3 `JLabel` instances on it with 3 different colors.

1. WHITE
2. RED
3. WHITE

This is my code:

```
package View;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Home extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label, label1;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Container window = getContentPane();

    public Home (){
        initGUI();
    }

    public void initGUI(){
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        label = new JLabel();       
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 266, 800);
        label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        this.add(label);

        panel = new JPanel();

        pack();
    }
}
```

But when i add a second label with the color red which must be standing next to the white color background, the white background will dissapear

Comment: Where are your 3 labels? I see only 2 in your code. And only 1 is instantiated and added.

Comment: You already use label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);. Is it difficult to apply them same for other labels? Does it require you to ask a question like that in this fantastic website? specify our question.

Comment: Do check as to what you are writng `label.setBounds(0, 0, 266, 800);`. the next label must be at `label.setBounds(267, 0, 266, 800);`and `label3.setBounds(533, 0, 266, 800);`, so that one comes after the other. Hope providing bounds at the wrong place is not an issue. Do check that :-)

Comment: 1) Put text in the labels for debugging purposes.  What strings do you see? 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Use layouts!

Comment: Did you check the layout. Probably the elements are getting added on top of one another. Please share the code of adding the second label as well.

Comment: Here's another option using `JLabel` (`new JLabel("<html><span bgcolor='yellow'>Yellow</span>&nbsp;<span bgcolor='red'>Red</span></html>")`), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290385/48136

Answer (score 0):

use html as text label as

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String initialText = "<html>\n" +
    "Color and font test:\n" +
    "<table>"+
    "<ul>\n" +
    "<tr>"+
    "<td bgcolor=\"#C0C0C0\">"+
    "<li><font color=red>red</font>\n" +
    "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "<td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\">"+
    "<li><font color=blue>blue</font>\n" +
    "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "<td bgcolor=\"#800000\">"+
    "<li><font color=green>green</font>\n" +
    "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFF00\">"+
    "<li><font size=-2>small</font>\n" +
    "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "<td bgcolor=\"#808000\">"+
    "<li><font size=+2>large</font>\n" +
    "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "<td bgcolor=\"#00FFFF\">"+
    "<li><i>italic</i>\n" +
    "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "<td bgcolor=\"#008080\">"+
    "<li><b>bold</b>\n" +
    "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
    "</ul>\n"+
    "</table>"
    ;
    JFrame f = new JFrame("This is a test");
    f.setSize(400, 150);
    Container content = f.getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.white);
    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    content.add(new JLabel(initialText));


    f.setVisible(true);
  }
```

}