# Can I highlight text in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, text, jlabel

I have a JLabel with some text in it. This JLabel takes up the whole bottom side of my JFrame. I have changed the background of it to yellow, and the whole bottom side becomes yellow. Is there any way to make it look like the text, which is within the JLabel, is being "highlighted"  with only the text having a background color of yellow, and the rest having a different color? The top part of my JFrame is a JPanel.

```
combo.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());
JPanel container = new JPanel();
container.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

response.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman", Font.BOLD, 40));
response.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

response.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
response.setOpaque(true);
add(response , BorderLayout.CENTER);
container.add(selectone);
container.add(combo);
this.add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: From what I saw, there is no default method to do such a thing, you may look a this post though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376216/how-to-highlight-part-of-a-jlabel-at-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do that - use HTML in the text of the label. Mind you, Swing interprets a pretty [old version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) of HTML, that doesn't meet today's standards.

```
JLabel response = new JLabel( "<html><span bgcolor=\"yellow\">This is the label text</span></html>" );
```

Nowadays, one should work with style sheets. But if you want to do that, you should probably switch from Swing to JavaFX.

For further details on using HTML in Swing components, see the [applicable part of the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Until now I didn't know you could add HTML commands into java! Could you please explain a little bit about adding HTML into Swing? I will mark you as best answer, and like your answer as soon as I understand. Thanks.

Comment: A label only has one background. The background around the label is the parent component, which is why I suggested nesting panels.

Comment: `Could you please explain a little bit about adding HTML into Swing?` - read the tutorial. How many times do you need to be pointed to the tutorial for the basics??? Search the trail contents. `I will mark you as best answer,` if it is the best answer then accept it now because "your original question" has been answered.

Answer (score 3):

Use a wrapper panel that respects the preferred size of the label:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("...");
label.setOpaque( true );
label.setBackground(...);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( label );
frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The default layout for a JPanel is a `FlowLayout` that is horizontally center aligned.

If you want both horizontal and vertical centering then use a `GridBagLayout` on the panel, with the default `GrigBagConstraints` when you add the label to the panel.

Comment: Although you weren't marked best answer, I have thanked you by lliking your answer. Thanks so much!